# Use angular material in custom angular library

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-library

I have an angular libraries project. I want to use external libraries in that project but I am unable to do so. I installed angular material and imported the MatIconModule in one of my library's module. But it still throws error **mat-icon is not a known element** can anybody please help.

Here is what my button module looks like:

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ButtonComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  exports: [ButtonComponent]
})
export class ButtonModule { }
```

And here is the component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ui-button',
  template: `
    <button 
      (click)="onClick.emit($event)"
      [ngClass]="getClasses()" 
      [disabled]="disabled"
      [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': backgroundColor }"
    ><mat-icon>cloud_download</mat-icon>{{label}}</button>
  `,
  styles: []
});
```

Here is the project package.json dependencies

[image]

And here is the button library package.json file

[image]

Comment: Post some codes that you have tried so we can see if you're on the right path

Comment: @Nipuna code updated

Comment: Can you share your lib `package.json` and project `package.json` (where you installed the `@angular/material`)

Comment: @ibenjelloun pictures added

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Yes, I was finally able to solve it!